# SyntaxError: invalid syntax with return function

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have been trying to use a piece of code that takes an array as input and draws a circle. I keep getting a syntax error. Can someone tell me whats wrong?

```
def planet_maker(a,b,n,r,array,p):
    import numpy as np




    y,x = np.ogrid[-a:n[0]-a, -b:n[1]-b]
    mask = x*x + y*y <= r*r


    return array[mask]=p
array=np.zeros([10,10])
planet_maker(1,1,[10,10],4,1)
```

> File "mapmaker.py", line 11
>       return array[mask] = p
>                          ^
>   SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: You cannot use `return` and `=` (assignment) in the same expression!  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Oh thanks! I did not know that.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use = and return in the same assignment.